# Разные версии модулей python при развёртывании

Tags: python, веб-программирование, flask, visual-studio-code, развертывание

Я разрабатывал приложение на flask(python) и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что в IDE виртуальная среда работает нормально(я работаю в VSCode), но при попытке запустить приложение через cmd(из той же виртуальной среды) выдаются ошибки об отсутствии какого-либо модуля. 
requirements.txt через IDE:

```
aiohttp==3.6.2
altgraph==0.16.1
astroid==2.3.3
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==19.3.0
bcrypt==3.1.7
blinker==1.4
certifi==2019.11.28
cffi==1.13.2
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
colorama==0.4.1
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
future==0.18.2
idna==2.8
isort==4.3.21
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.3
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mccabe==0.6.1
multidict==4.6.1
numpy==1.17.4
pefile==2019.4.18
Pillow==6.2.1
pycparser==2.19
pygame==1.9.6
PyInstaller==4.0.dev0+9dd34bdfba
pylint==2.4.4
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
requests==2.22.0
six==1.13.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.11
urllib3==1.25.7
virtualenv==16.7.8
Werkzeug==0.16.0
wrapt==1.11.2
WTForms==2.2.1
yarl==1.4.2
```

requirements.txt через cmd:

```
alembic==1.3.2
Click==7.0
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Ext==0.1
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Flask-Migrate==2.5.2
Flask-Session==0.3.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.3
Mako==1.1.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mypy==0.760
mypy-extensions==0.4.3
Pillow==6.2.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-editor==1.0.4
redis==3.3.11
six==1.13.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.12
typed-ast==1.4.0
typing-extensions==3.7.4.1
Werkzeug==0.16.0
WTForms==2.2.1
WTForms-Ext==0.2
WTForms-SQLAlchemy==0.1
```

При том при попытке установить в командной строке модули в которых возникла ошибка, мне выводит сообщение, что модуль уже установлен, что меня окончательно убивает.
Вот мой файл с настройками, если кому интересно:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
import os
from flask_migrate import Migrate


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:////{os.getcwd()}/carleasingdatabase.db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'GITGUDHACCKAZ'
db = SQLAlchemy(app, session_options={
    'expire_on_commit': False,
})

login_manager = LoginManager(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
delim = os.path.sep
static_path = f'{os.getcwd()}{delim}application{delim}flaskcarleasing{delim}static'

MODERATOR_TOKEN = os.environ['MODERATOR_TOKEN']

from users.routes import users
from cars.routes import cars
from concerns.routes import concerns
from main.routes import main
from leasing.routes import leasing


app.register_blueprint(users, url_prefix='/users')
app.register_blueprint(cars, url_prefix='/cars')
app.register_blueprint(concerns, url_prefix='/concerns')
app.register_blueprint(leasing, url_prefix='/leasing')
app.register_blueprint(main)
```

Как это исправить? Из-за этого не могу нормально развернуть приложение, уже не знаю что делать. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что такое "через IDE" и "через cmd"? requirements.txt это обычный текстовый файл, который не должен ни капельки меняться сам по себе в любом месте - хоть через MS-DOS его читайте. Так что непонятно, о чём вы тут вообще говорите

Comment: А вы ставили на чистый питон через `pip install -r requirements.txt`?

Comment: @andreymal я имею в виду, что  создал виртуальную среду и к ней подключился через ide, всё работает нормально. Когда хочу развернуть приложение и запустить его просто через командную строку, напрямую открыть файл app.py, то он мне говорит что нету каких-то модулей, хотя я через ту же виртуальную среду захожу, что и в ide.

Comment: @gil9red нет, я пробовал только ставить на виртуальную среду напрямую модули из requirements.txt, но выдаётся ошибка, что они уже установлены. В том-то и прикол, что когда я запускаю приложение - выдаётся ошибка что таких-то модулей нет, а когда пытаюсь их установить тоже выдаётся ошибка, что модуль уже есть и нельзя установить его повторно :D

Comment: @GreedWizard, значит у вас несколько питонов стоят, скорее всего используете, мб неявно, **venv**. Ставьте модули тому питону, который вы запускаете